# Python, phone book

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

ok, it's the first time i'm working with python and i'm making a phone book.

```
enter code here
from tkinter import*

def delete():
     select=listbox.curselection()
     index=select[0]
     listbox.delete(index)

def add():
    name=entry1.get()
    telephone=entry2.get()
    name.set("")
    telephone.set("")
    listbox.insert(END, name+ ': ' + telephone)
    if name=="":
        labelError=Label(frame1, text="Name is empty", fg="red")
        labelError.grid(columnspan=2)
    if telephone=="":
        labelError2=Label(frame1, text="Telephone is empty", fg="red")
        labelError2.grid(columnspan=2)

def save():
    list1=list(listbox.get(0,END))
    f=open("output.txt", "w")
    f.writelines(str(list1))
    f.close()

wn=Tk()
wn.geometry("400x350")
wn.title("Telephone")

frame1=Frame(wn)
frame2=Frame(wn)
frame1.pack()
frame2.pack()

label1=Label(frame1, text="List of contacts", font="Calibre 30")
label1.grid(row=0, columnspan=2)
label2=Label(frame1, text="Name:", font="Calibre 18")
label2.grid(row=1, column=0)
label3=Label(frame1, text="Telephone:", font="Calibre 18")
label3.grid(row=2, column=0)

name=StringVar()
entry1=Entry(frame1,textvariable=name)
entry1.grid(row=1, column=1)

telephone=StringVar()
entry2=Entry(frame1,textvariable=telephone)
entry2.grid(row=2, column=1)

scrollbar=Scrollbar(frame2, orient=VERTICAL)

listbox=Listbox(frame2, selectmode=EXTENDED, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set,width=40) 
listbox.grid(row=3, columnspan=3)

scrollbar.config(command=listbox)


button1=Button(frame2, text="Add", width=15, height=1, command=add)
button1.grid(row=5, column=0)

button2=Button(frame2, text="Delete",  width=15, height=1, command=delete)
button2.grid(row=5, column=1)

button3=Button(frame2, text="Save to file",  width=15, height=1, command=save)
button3.grid(row=5, column=2)

wn.mainloop()
```

in the def add i have name.set("")

when i tried to run it i had this error:

```
enter code here
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1533, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Sana\Desktop\Sana\python\telephone.py", line 11, in add
    name.set("")
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'set'
```

however i wrote that my name is StringVar, not just a str. What can I do?
Also, I want to edit my listbox, I mean choose one string (name + telephone) and edit it while running, what can I do?
By the way, I wrote name.set("") cuz I want my entries to be empty each time when i add new contact.

Comment: `name=entry1.get()`. You're setting it to a string. It doesn't matter what you do later in the code. At that point `name` is equal to the return value of `entry1.get()`, which is a string in this case.

Answer (score 2):

```
def add():
    name = entry1.get()
    telephone = entry2.get()
    name.set("")
    telephone.set("")
```

`name` (and `telephone`) are strings (since `entry.get` returns a string). Strings don't have a `set` attribute in Python, hence the error that you receive.

You meant to do `entry1.set` and `entry2.set`.